# Android. Call recording

Tags: android, audio-recording

My app records calls using standard MediaRecorder.
After a few seconds after incoming call started, starting call recording (MediaRecorder.start).
After this, interlocutor hear me very bad.
If I connect/disconnect headphones during recording, then problem disappeared.
How do resolve the problem programmatically?

Comment: hi drewha, can you please post your code, actually my requirements are same like you. So please it will be very much appreciable if you provide me source.

Comment: Can you please share the code on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this problem. AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn() true then false helped me.
Thanks to all.

Comment: If you accept your own answer, then this question will be marked "answered". Thanks! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: When do you call setSpeakerphoneOn exactly? When do you set it to true and when to false? Do you enable it for the whole time of recording? Or have you found a workaround that doesn't require the speakers to be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is possible on some phones, but the general answer is that you can't record calls. The streams for voice are in a lower level of the operating system and aren't accessible on the "application level".

Comment: Am I right - phone hardware allows this (after rejecking headphones it works fine), but due to program (Android) limitations it is not allowed to do this programmatically? It is on HTC Sensation. On Samsung Galaxy2 it works fine at all, without manual operations.

Comment: What you have written is exactly correct. In some cases it works, but generally (and by Android standards) it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Plus it is illegal unless you follow some very strict guidelines, see the link.

http://transition.fcc.gov/cgb/consumerfacts/recordcalls.html

Comment: I know this. In may case it is legal.